# Импорт CSV в Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Доброй ночи. Импортирую каталог товаров из csv файла в торговый каталог. Импорт проходит успешно, но все товары становятся недоступны к покупкам. Импорт делаю по документации, версия Битрикс коммерческая.

Comment: По какой причине товары не доступны? Товары не активны или у них остаток нулевой?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Остаток нулевой.

Comment: Проверьте что в csv загружается остаток. Проверьте, что он это поле в настройках импорта отмечено как CATALOG_QUANTITY. Проверьте  для каждого типа цены который вы загружаете, грузятся также и валюты. Проверьте что CATALOG_QUANTITY выбран в настройках модуля торговый каталог в списке полей участвующих в импорте.

Comment: Спасибо вам за советы, видимо, в другом проблема, потому что я импортирую этот же каталог в другой сайт, на другом хостинге и там товары уже доступны.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно у вас в настройках торгового каталога указано "по умолчанию" вести количественный учет, в таком случае при выгрузке товаров, без указания количества, они автоматически будет недоступны, так-как количество товара 0 а учет ведется, поэтому товар не доступен к покупке...